# WPF - How do I default the Visibility of a databound Textblock?

Tags: wpf, default, visibility, textblock, databound

This Textblock, defined below, shows when the window first loads because it has no Datacontext (and hence the converter code is not run) until an item has been selected from another control e.g. TreeView.

```
<TextBlock
   Name="tbkDocumentNotFound" 
   Style="{StaticResource StandardText}"
   Margin="4,4,2,0" 
   TextWrapping="Wrap"                                    
   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsDownloaded, Converter={StaticResource docNotFoundVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
   Text="The document could not be found.">
</TextBlock>
```

So how do I stop the it from appearing when it has no DataContext?

Thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To provide a default value (used when the target of a Binding can't be found) you use the `FallbackValue`, for example:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsDownloaded, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
```

This should be the case when there is no DataContext.

Comment: Thanks GraemeF.

Although I'll just point out that the just the Member name should be specified i.e.

Visibility="{Binding Path=IsDownloaded, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"

Comment: This just saved me a lot of time and energy THANK YOU!